# How to subscribe a socket channel using SocketIO?

Tags: ios, swift, laravel, socket.io

I am trying to connect to a specific channel so that I can only listen events emitted to that channel. I have used Laravel Echo on server side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally after spending some time on this issue I got the solution. Here is the solution

```
private let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://testserver.com:6001")!, config: [.log(true), .compress, .reconnects(true), .reconnectAttempts(-1), .forceWebsockets(true), .forcePolling(true)])
private var socket: SocketIOClient!
private var nameSpace = "App\\Events\\"

func connect() {
    socket = manager.defaultSocket
    socket.connect()
    socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
        let channelData = ["channel": "test-channel"]
        self.socket.emit("subscribe", channelData) {
            print("Sockets: test-channel subscribed")
            socket.on("\(nameSpace)newMessage") { (data, ack) in
                print("Sockets: newMessage event called")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please also add links to relevant third party code (`SocketManager` and `SocketIOClient`)

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz Link added to the GitHub Repository of Socket.IO-Client-Swift

Answer (score 0):

I would look into URLSessionWebSocketTask.. it's a bit weird how they set up the API but it's the only option in the standard library. I added a link below to get started..

https://medium.com/better-programming/websockets-in-ios-13-using-swift-and-xcode-11-18fa3000d802

As for the channel subscription, you'll most likely need to send messages through the socket and saving a reference of that channel on the backend. This is what the frontend code might look like..

https://github.com/BJBeecher/Networking/blob/master/Sources/Networking/WebSockets/WebSocket.swift